# Query optimization is showing Key doesn't exist in table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I am working on query optimization. I have run explain command followed by my query few explain query optimization related records it is displayed. In that It is showing 'possible_keys' and 'Extra' field names. I have searched for 'Use force index with possible keys', I have got to know that I can use the keyword 'use index (index_list)' in the query which I am trying to optimize.

**I have a doubt that in place of 'index_list' which type of index name to use I mean shall I use column names with aliases which I have used in the query (or) shall I use index names of respective tables used in the query which I created when tables created**.

I have given index names of table then it is showing the error below:

```
ERROR 1176 (42000): Key 'index_name' doesn't exist in table 'ecs'
```

Any tips/suggestions of Query optimization also welcome. Any help would be appreciated..! Thanks.

Comment: Show us the query and the schema; we will help you optimize it.  Hint: `FORCE INDEX` is usually the _wrong_ approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an index hint like `use index(<name...>)` or `force index(<name...>)` you must use index names.

Don't use column names or column aliases.

You can find out what indexes are defined in your table with one of these statements:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES IN ecs;

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE ecs\G
```

Index and key are often synonyms to MySQL, so the indexes may be called a key.

Comment: Thank you for the solution brother, but I am here thinking how to apply for my query. will get back to you once it is done.